# how to share link in social site from angular app

Tags: angular, hyperlink, meta-tags

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Social Media share</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./assets/icons/icon-192x192.png">

  <meta name="description" content="Put your description here.">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="637933296725159" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://social-519.web.app" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Introducing our New Site" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://social-519.web.app/assets/images/tiger.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="THis is basic description on out wesite " /> 
</head>
```

I have added meta tags on my index.html file. I have also tried not to add these tags on index file rather add the tags using add tag method from other component. but then facebook debugger doesn't find og properties. That's why I had to add tags here

[image]

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

this.title.setTitle("Third component Title");

this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: 'third , third component' });
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'this is third component description ' });
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'third' }, 'property="og:type"');
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: 'https://social-519.web.app/third' }, 'property="og:url"');
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'This is third Title' }, 'property="og:title"');
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: 'https://social-519.web.app/assets/images/one.jpg' }, 'property="og:image"');
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: 'This is Third description in our webvsite' }, 'property="og:description"');


}
```

[I have updated the meta tags here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DabyV.png)

But unfortunately the tags are not being updated and as a result my shared card is showing the default picture that has been added to the index.html page.

How do I update the tags and make the tags dynamic?

Comment: Could you try to remove the tag that you have in the `index.html` file, and only use them inside the different `ngOnInit()` of your pages? Because the way you're using the meta library seems to be ok

Comment: It has been tried before but does not work